# Spring Autowired doesnt work in BeanConfig

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a Spring Server running and up to now I had no problems with autowiring my Beans through field injection. For some Reason this doesnt work under certain circumstances. I want to achieve that my DatabaseConfiguration is autowired inside the Database classes. The DatabaseConfiguration is loaded from the application properties with the

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databaseConfiguration")
```

annotations. It loads successfully inside my BeanConfig where I have autowired this class. Now I have a bean definition for a Database like this:

```
@Bean
public Database getDatabase() {
    return new Database();
}
```

Inside the Database class there is a field definition for the Configuration like this:

```
@Autowired
DatabaseConfiguration config;
```

When the getDatabase() function is called, i verified that the DatabaseConfiguration gets correctly autowired inside the BeanConfig class, but for some reason it is null inside the created instance of the Database.

the Database class is inside the project.databases package, the DatabaseConiguration and BeanConfiguration is inside the project.config package.

my main application is inside the project package and is annotated with these annotations

```
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Does anyone have a clue why the autowiring doesnt work here?

Answer (score 0):

You create the Database manually - `return new Database();`. Spring has no chance to autowire anything.

You should either let Spring create the bean or assign the config manually.